# Deploying NodeJS using Travis CI and GIT (setup by POD)

Tags: node.js, git, travis-ci

**My goal :**
Continuous integration, then deploy if the build is on a specific branch.
The push should be to a server hosting a [pod](https://github.com/yyx990803/pod) instance.
It is basically a git bare repository where I can push. When I push a hook triggered and voilà.

**My Problem :**
At the end of [the build](https://travis-ci.org/SponsorDetector/sponsor-detector-server/builds/131147397), ssh is asking for a password.

**My configuration :**

***.travis.yml :***

```
before_install:
  - openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_9bbc0c90c60c_key -iv $encrypted_9bbc0c90c60c_iv
    -in key.enc -out key -d
addons:
  ssh_known_hosts: dev.ogdabou.ninja
after_success:
  - if [[ $TRAVIS_BRANCH == "dev" ]]; then chmod 750 deploy.sh; ./deploy.sh; fi
```

where `key`is a private ssh key having ssh password-less authentification to the server.

***deploy.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
chmod 600 key
mv key ~/.ssh/id_rsa
cd dist;
pwd;
git init;
git config --global user.name "travis"
git config --global user.email "travis@github.com"
git remote add deploy $DEV_DEPLOY_REPO;
git add .;
git commit -m "Build $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER";
git push deploy master;
```

Thanks for your help :).

Comment: Use a passwordless key

Answer (score 0):

The first time I tried I used the server hosting the POD service. 
It is now working, created a user in cygwin, new ssh key then configured password-less ssh.
Finally, encode travis keys and follow travis tutorial.